# What is the correct way to replicate the SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT columnname ) in Excel, via formula or VBS

Tags: excel, excel-formula

trying to replicate the SQL statment  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT columnname ) in Excel. The issue is that the values in the target column are alphanumerical in order, including dashes

I have tried these formulas:

1. `=SUM(1/COUNTIF(Range, Range))` but I get as a result 0.
2. `=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(MATCH(Column, Column, 0), ROW(Column)-ROW(Column[1])+1)>0))` but I get as a result 0. Don't forget that you should put it in matrix format, pressing SHIFT + CONTROL + ENTER.

Comment: I assume your version of  Excel does not support the `UNIQUE` formula?

Comment: Please include a minimal mock up of the data in a markdown table as well as expected output.

Comment: also if you are not using office 365, change the `SUM` to `SUMPRODUCT`

Comment: Removed SQL tag as you're looking only for an Excel solution.